# How to define a Laravel route with a parameter that contains a slash character

Tags: php, laravel

I want to define a route with a parameter that will contain a slash `/` character like so `example.com/view/abc/02` where `abc/02` is the parameter.

How can I prevent Laravel from reading the slash as a separator for the next route parameter? Because of that I'm getting a `404 not found error` now.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Add the below catch-all route to the bottom of your `routes.php` and remember to run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards. Notice the use of "->where" that specifies the possible content of params, enabling you to use a param containing a slash.

```
//routes.php
Route::get('view/{slashData?}', 'ExampleController@getData')
    ->where('slashData', '(.*)');
```

And than in your controller you just handle the data as you'd normally do (like it didnt contain the slash).

```
//controller 
class ExampleController extends BaseController {

    public function getData($slashData = null)
    {
        if($slashData) 
        {
            //do stuff 
        }
    }

}
```

This should work for you.

Additionally, here you have detailed Laravel docs on route parameters: [ [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) ]

Comment: I disagree, this is a hack to work around a short-fall in the laravel routing. Check out my answer and laravel package which provides a fix for encoded slashes.

Comment: It works similar in Lumen `$app->get('/documents/{document:.+}', 'DocumentController@show');`

Comment: In my use case, I have another parameter after the "slash-parameter" like this: `url/slash%2Fparameter/12`- with a route like `url/{slashData}/{id}`. This should work, but doesn't due to laravels bug. Your "solution" would give `getData()` the whole `slash/parameter/12` and I would have to split the slash-parameter from the id myself. That's laravel's job, not mine!

Comment: @Chistopher K. you can accept slash parameters perfectly just don't use url encoding on the slash; that is a separate bug in Laravel (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22125). 
But if you use url/slash/parameter/12 for your example and then create the route like this: Route::get('/url/{slashData}/{id}', 'SomeController@someMethod')->where(['slashData' => '[^/]+/[^/]+','id' => '[0-9]+'])
It will work just fine (tested with Laravel 5.6).

Comment: how is this '(.*)' mean this '/' ?

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar issue but my URL contains several route parameters :

```
/test/{param1WithSlash}/{param2}/{param3}
```

And here is how I managed that case :

```
    Route::get('test/{param1WithSlash}/{param2}/{param3}', function ($param1MayContainsSlash, $param2, $param3) {

        $content = "PATH: " . Request::path() . "</br>";
        $content .= "PARAM1: $param1WithSlash </br>";
        $content .= "PARAM2: $param2 </br>".PHP_EOL;
        $content .= "PARAM3: $param3 </br>".PHP_EOL;

        return Response::make($content);
    })->where('param1MayContainsSlash', '(.*(?:%2F:)?.*)');
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This is working on my end, and also works for multiple parameters each containing one or more slashes.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. This is indeed the standard solution because it is recommended by the Laravel's doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 8):

urlencoded slashes do not work in Laravel due to what I consider a bug.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4323
This pull request will resolve that bug.

Update.

Note that the change allows the route to be parsed BEFORE decoding the values in the path.

Comment: bug fix denied so I wrote a package... github.com/Artistan/Urlencode

Comment: It definitely is a bug, and it bit me again today in Laravel 10 (last time was about 5 years ago). More specifically, it looks like some conceptual problem. It seems like a related issue that e. g. `route('search', 'LED (red/green)')` returns "https://example.com/search/LED%20%28red/green%29", where spaces and brackets are encoded, but not the slash. There has to be some reasoning behind that.

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 8+

```
Route::get('/search/{search}', function ($search) {
    return $search;
})->where('search', '.*');
```

Reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes

Comment: Ah! The power of proper documentation!

Answer (score 4):

I've already upvoted [Pierre](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)'s answer, it's correct, but in my opinion is longer than needed, here's a very short for-the-impatient sample route that does the trick:

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->where('slug', '[\w\s\-_\/]+');
```

This is all you need. Indeed, the `\/` in the regular expression above(in the `where` method) is all you need !

Now for example:

- domain/A ---> "A" will be passed to the `show` method of the `PostController`.
- domain/A/B ---> "A/B" will be passed to the `show` method of the `PostController`.
- domain/A/B/C ---> "A/B/C" will be passed to the `show` method of the `PostController`.
- and so on...

For more samples read this: [Laravel Documentation - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)