# Laravel stripping $_GET parameters

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I am setting up an OAuth2 callback, and Laravel appears to be stripping any parameters passed via the URL (aka GET). This includes `Input::get()`, `Input::all()`, as well as the general PHP `$_GET` and even `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

My initial reaction was an Nginx config error. But I am able to setup a test PHP file in my laravel/public directory which simply is:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET)
```

Hitting `/test.php?code=123456ABCD` generates the expected dump of an single value array.

Then, in Laravel routes, I create,

```
Route::get('/testcallback', function(){
    var_dump(Input::all());
});
```

Hitting `/testcallback?code=123456ABCD` generates the dumping of an empty array.

Is there something I am doing in my config or routes that would cause Laravel to strip the GET parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552604/how-to-define-a-laravel-route-with-a-parameter-that-contains-a-slash-character

Comment: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5447

Comment: @Kapilgopinath What's the meaning of those links? Did you read the first one you posted? Where are the "slashes in the url" in OP's question?

Comment: Damien I guess the url format used by Dustin is not a right one. The urls that I posted gives some insight to the right way of creating url's. Moreover the first post also mentions some issue with the slash character when used in the url.

Comment: Dustin - I tried your code - and it works for me on a nginx server on Laravel 4.1. There must be something wrong with your server setup somewhere for the redirect to index.php perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the test @TheShiftExchange that at least confirmed that it is not a Laravel issue and got me looking back at Nginx. Looks like there was a broken symlink in my Nginx sites.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being Nginx after all. Turns out the symlink between my sites-available and sites-enabled host had broken, and the (well documented) solutions to the query_string issue was not flowing through.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

This was fixed by simply removing the sites-enabled site, and relinking it, then restarting Nginx.

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{site-name}
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/{site-name} /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{site-name}
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx reload
```