# Laravel $_GET parameters are not received in controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, nginx, digital-ocean

I am a newbie for Laravel framework.

I am trying out a simple URL "`http://localhost/test?code=value`" and when trying to access the value of `code` in controller like `$_GET["code"]` or `Input::get('code')`, I could not access the value in my controller.

I am using digitalocean server with nginx server.

Here is .htaccess file in my project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

When i tried with simple php script in test.php file `<?php 
    print_r($_GET);
?>` I can access the values. So, I believe there is no problem with my server settings.

I tried the answer mentioned for similar issue [Laravel stripping $_GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820746/laravel-stripping-get-parameters) but it didnt work for me.

Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck for long time :(

Comment: that htaccess file is useless since you are in `nginx` server. what is your `nginx.conf?`

Comment: Is the folder name test? or is the file named test.php?

Comment: I have a route defined as test in routes.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue. There was a mis-configuration in nginx server. In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, instead of having below configuration `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`, it was `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;` without a `?`. After adding ? everything became normal.