# How to pass forward slash (%2F) in laravel 5 url with additional get parameters

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

Users can search my site. Sometimes they might use a search term containing a forward slash (search with / slash) which when submitted by the form turns into %2F in the url.

For example

```
www.mysite.com/search/search+with+%2F+slash
```

I have used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552604/how-to-define-a-laravel-route-with-a-parameter-that-contains-a-slash-character) which works great to give me the right page and not return a 404.

My problem now is I use pagination on the page and custom filters which are both passed as get vars in the url and when accessing the GET var it's empty.

For example

```
www.mysite.com/search/search+with+%2F+slash?page=2
```

This is my current route

```
$this->get('search/{search_term}', ['uses' => 'SearchController@search'])
->where('search_term', '(.*(?:%2F:)?.*)');
```

Not sure what do from here

Comment: You would not have to take care of the encoded characters in the url. That's why I think you have to use a far simpler regex, you have to escape the `?` also I think.

Comment: I'm not great at regex. Maybe you can offer a regex solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including an encoded slash (`%2F`) in the path component of a URL is not a good idea. [The HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.3) says that this sequence should be "equivalent" to a real slash:

> Characters other than those in the "reserved" and "unsafe" sets (see
> RFC 2396 [42]) are equivalent to their ""%" HEX HEX" encoding.

In practice, the handling of these URLs is inconsistent. Some web servers (and even some browsers!) will treat `%2F` as equivalent to a real slash, some will treat it differently, and some tools, including some web application firewalls and proxies, will simply reject URLs which contain such a sequence.

If you need to include user input like this in a URL, you should probably put it in a query string (`/search/?q=search+with+%2f+slash`).

Comment: Actually, the RFC says it's **not** equivalent to the HEX encoding, as the `/` is part of the reserved set.

Comment: Downvoted because no change and no answer in almost 3 years. This has been a controversial issue on Github as well, as Laravel *clearly* violates the RFC. See here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4338

Comment: @aross agreed. His quoted excerpt of the RFC does not apply to the forward-slash / as it's part of the reserved list. He left out that crucial part of the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a double url encode for `"/"` -> `"%2F"` -> `"%252F"`, that is far from ideal, but gets the job done :

```
www.mysite.com/search/search+with+%2F+slash
```

1. ```
   str_replace("%2F", "%252F", "search+with+%2F+slash") // double url encode for "/"
   ```
2. Now it will become a suitable `"search+with+%252F+slash"` for the browser
3. laravel will do the first url decode and it will appear as "search with %2F slash" inside your controller
4. you can do `str_replace("%2F", "/", "search with %2F slash")` to get
   the back the original text