# Passing values in the URL with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to turn this url

`http://example.com/search?values[]=foo&values[]=bar&more[]=baz&more[]=fab`

into something a bit more friendly?

`http://example.com/search/values/<mutliple-items>/more/<mutliple-items>`

Comment: as you wish :) Just specify it in the routes: `Route::get('search/values/{mutliple_items}/more/{mutliple_items2}/', ['uses' => "SearchController@index"]);`

Comment: how do you separate the items though without them coming out as a string? Ideally I would want an array like in the first option.

Comment: Not sure if this functionality is available in v5, but in v4 there was `Route::when('search/*' ... ` And then you can parse those values

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552604/how-to-define-a-laravel-route-with-a-parameter-that-contains-a-slash-character

Comment: Thanks Alex, got it working via your link

Comment: u r welcome bro )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by @alexslipknot

```
Route::get('search/values/{slashValues?}/more/{slashMore?}', 'Website\SearchController@searchTest')
    ->where('slashValues', '(.*)')
    ->where('slashMore', '(.*)');
```

and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Route::get('search/values/{mutliple_items1}/more/{mutliple_it‌​ems2}', 'SearchController@search');
```