# Unable to fetch get parameter with encoded '/' in Laravel using route

Tags: laravel, url-routing

I am new to Laravel and working on existing code.

I want to pass some *values in url* in format of ***URL/val1/val2/val3***.

Every thing is working perfect if all values with normal string or number

but if any value has special character like **slash** / or  \ it shows errors.

eg.
**working** :- URL/abc/pqr/xys

but if val3 = 22/06 ;url is URL/val1/val2/22/06 error shows **404 not found**

If I encoded val3 using javaScript's function **encodeURIComponent()**

val3=22%2F06 and url become **URL/val1/val2/22%2F06** shows **Object not found!**

```
 // My current route web.php is:-

    Route::get('/export/{name}/{status}/{search}', 'ReportController@export')->name('export');
```

Comment: You can use this as a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552604/how-to-define-a-laravel-route-with-a-parameter-that-contains-a-slash-character

Comment: @satish When you have passed `/` that understand new params so you must define the condition en route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//routes.php
Route::get('view/{slashData?}', 'ExampleController@getData')
    ->where('slashData', '(.*)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route accept only 3 params. But you pass four params.

```
Route::get('/export/{name}/{status}/{search}', 'ReportController@export')->name('export');
```

You must change your val3=22-06. Don't use / as value of your param.

Eg.

```
URL/val1/val2/22-06
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex expression for that situation:

```
Route::get('/export/{name}/{status}/{search}', 'ReportController@export')->name('export')->where(['search' => "[\w\/]+"]);
```